# Pyramid Authentication/Authorization implementation

Tags: python, authentication, authorization, pyramid

*Software: Python 2.7.9, Pyramid 1.5.7*

## Updates

The issue I kept coming across was the inability of `group_finder` to return the value of the retrieved `user` and their respective `group` from the database. This became worse when validating the user's permissions (`ACE`/`ACL`) since the two did not match. I created a custom `group_finder` function that would print out the retrieved results to match the `ACL` permissions. With that said, I still find that this function needs conditionals to handle an unrecognized username / password. As of right now it breaks the program. What type of `If` statement should I include to handle `None`?

**Working callback function, but needs `if` statement to handle unknown `userid`:**

```
def groupfinder(userid, request):
    print '#'*80
    print userid # this is the username
    group_name = api.retrieve_group_byusername(userid) # retrieves user and returns [Group(group_name='')]
    print 'group_name', group_name[0].group_name # Registered User
    gp = group_name[0].group_name
    print 'gp', gp #gp Registered User
    print ['g:%s' % gp] # [u'g:Registered User']
    return ['g:%s' % gp] #[u'g:Registered User']
```

---

**Original Error:**
I am trying to implement the SQLAlchemy `User` and `Group` classes via the Pyramid `groupfinder` function and `RootFactory`. I created a nifty API using CRUD for retrieving `user` by `group` and `group` by `user` etc...

After going through Pyramid's [tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html) and this awesome ['Group-Level' tutorial](http://michael.merickel.org/projects/pyramid_auth_demo/group_security.html), I am still struggling with the nuts and bolts of getting users authenticated and authorized. It's currently not working. I've noticed that the terminal prints `ACLDenied permission 'create' via ACE '` ... despite the fact that permission is granted.

I am looking specifically at the `Registered User` view. `Root Factory` is established exactly as shown in the [Pyramid Tutorial Wiki](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/authorization.html).

**original code:**

```
    #API from db for api.retrieve_group_byuser(username)
    
        def retrieve_group_byuser(self, username):
                # retrieves a group by username
                query = self.session.query(Group).\
                filter(Group.users.any(User.username == username)).all() #returns a list
                print "retrieved by username:", query
                return query
    
    #security.py
    
        from ..models import * #DB
            
        def groupfinder(userid, request):
            print '#'*80
            print userid # this is the username 
            group = api.retrieve_group_byuser(userid) # retrieves group by username
            if userid in group:
                return group(userid, [])
    
    #models.py (includes the import of the DB and API)
    
        class RootFactory(object):
            __acl__ = [ (Allow, Everyone, 'view'),
                    (Allow, 'group: Administrator', ALL_PERMISSIONS),
                    (Allow, 'group: Registered User', 'create')
                    ]
            def __init__(self, request):
                self.request = request
    
    #views **(default.py)**
    
        @view_config(route_name='login', renderer='templates/login.jinja2')
        @forbidden_view_config(renderer='templates/login.jinja2')
        def login(request):
            login_url = request.route_url('login')
            referrer = request.url
            if referrer == login_url:
                referrer = '/' # never use the login form itself as came_from
            came_from = request.params.get('came_from', referrer)
            message = ''
            login = ''
            password = ''
            if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
                login = request.params['login']
                password = request.params['password']
        
                user = api.retrieve_user(login)
                if(user is not None):
                    headers = remember(request, login)
                    return HTTPFound(location = came_from,
                                     headers = headers)
                message = 'Failed login'
        
            return dict(
                message = message,
                url = request.application_url + '/login',
                came_from = came_from,
                login = login,
                password = password,
                )
    
        @view_config(route_name='assessments', request_method='GET', renderer='templates/assessments.jinja2', permission='create')
        def view_assessments(request):
            login = authenticated_userid(request)
            if login is None: 
                raise HTTPForbidden()
            #more code
    
    #__init__.py (auth setup and routes)
    
        authn_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy(
        'sosecret', callback=groupfinder, hashalg='sha512')
        authz_policy = ACLAuthorizationPolicy()
        config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                            root_factory='notssweb.models.RootFactory')
        config.set_authentication_policy(authn_policy)
        config.set_authorization_policy(authz_policy)
    
        config.add_route('frontpage', '/')
        config.add_route('login', '/login')
        config.add_route('logout', '/logout')
        config.add_route('users', '/users')
        config.add_route('user', '/users/{id:\d+}/{login}')

    
    #Terminal prints: 
    
        starting subprocess with file monitor
        --db Session--
  ################################################################################
        dorisday # this is the userid being entered 
        retrieved by username: [<Group(group_name='Registered User')>] #this is the group_finder api printout
        2015-11-10 15:02:29,240 DEBUG [web][Dummy-3] debug_authorization of url http://0.0.0.0:6432/assessments (view name u'' against context <models.RootFactory object at 0x110005ad0>): ACLDenied permission 'create' via ACE '<default deny>' in ACL [('Allow', 'system.Everyone', 'view'), ('Allow', 'group: Administrator', <pyramid.security.AllPermissionsList object at 0x10e932d10>), ('Allow', 'group: Editor', ('add', 'edit')), ('Allow', 'group: Registered User', 'create')] on context <models.RootFactory object at 0x110005ad0> for principals ['system.Everyone']
```

Comment: Could you also include your route configuration (`add_route()` etc.)

Comment: Hello @MikkoOhtamaa I've added the routes :)

Comment: There are a lot of missing pieces to help. Where do you specify the RootFactory should be used? Where do you set the permission needed for a view? Which view are you executing? What is `group` that your API returns? Are you sure that `userid in group`?

Comment: @AntoineLeclair I added the things you mentioned above.